# Missing binding Node Sass

Tags: build, node-modules, yarnpkg

When I use "yarn build", i got an error message:

```
Error: Missing binding /www/htdocs/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
- Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

I tried to use     `npm rebuild node-sass` but it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be related to globally installed packages. 
I have been fighting getting a CMS package - Enduro - to work and finally I found a solution.

Normally Enduro is installed in `/usr/local/lib` however it can also be installed in the project. When I run Enduro from the `/usr/local/lib` I get the "sass version error" like you. However when I run the local project version `./node-modules/.bin/enduro` there is no version problems.

I got no clue how to fix the global installation since the bindings will not fix when I run the rebuild `sass` command.

But running Enduro from the project works fine for me for now.

I hope you can use some of this even if you are dealing with another product using Sass.